# Adaptive Card How to use Conditional Statements. If/Else or When

Tags: conditional-statements, botframework, adaptive-cards, visualizer, adaptive-design

I am using designer Adaptive Card.
I Need to display Specific Data With Each Choice Option in ChoiceSet Action.
Eg- If User Select "**PhoneCall**" from ChoiceSet-->
It should display other details for user to enter country code & Phone Number and Finally Submit the Information.
But If User Select "**TeamsChat**" from ChoiceSet-->It takes the Id No and just Submit the Contact Method.

Below i hve attached images for better understanding.

[image: Sample Imge]

[image: Sample Image]